# Single instance of the GNOME Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'd like to know or it is possible to set up the GNOME Terminal in a way that when I open up the terminal and there is already an instance open it'll show that instance and not open up a brand new one.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using, and which environment? I ask, because what you are describing is the default setup in unity and gnome-shell.

Comment: I’m using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity-2D. I haven’t done a clean install but an upgrade from 11.04.

Comment: Do you use Ctrl+Alt+T as a shortcut?

Comment: Yes I do.That or I start up a terminal typing “ter » enter” in Kupfer. Those are the the 2 methods I use. Because I don't look on the Unity laucher all too often I end up with 3, 4 different terminals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a simple shell script using wmctrl to give the Terminal focus. It does exactly what I want.

First, install wmctrl `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

Next, fire up a text-editor, copy the following lines.

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='gnome-terminal'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
  wmctrl -xa $SERVICE
else
  $SERVICE
fi
```

Save the file somewhere where you usually keep your shell scripts. In my case I did:  `~/bin/single_instance.sh`

cd to the directory (`cd ~/bin`) and make the file executable `chmod +x single_instance.sh`

Now, open up **Main Menu** select **Accessories » Terminal** press **properties** and replace command with the script: `~/bin/single_instance.sh`

Open up **System Settings » Keyboard » Shortcuts**. Disable **Launch Terminal** shortcut by giving it a backspace. Make a custom shortcut. Again fill in the path and name to the script and give it the key combination **ctrl + alt + t**.

You’re done, single instance terminal...

Comment: Why not just make your script the default terminal launcher? Why all the steps to add shortcuts and all? +1 for the script, -1 for the implementation.

Comment: In all honestly… I don't know how to do that. I’ve looked at default applications and didn't see terminal. Also I'm convinced that the previous version of Ubuntu had text-fields where commands could be entered. This version of default apps is all drop down menus.

Comment: anyway to get this working with wayland?

Answer (score 2):

Add **--tab** to the launcher command.  Then you end up with only one app. open.

```
~$ gnome-terminal --help-all
:
--tab       Open a new tab in the last-opened window with the default profile
```

Comment: No, I don't want a new tab. I want the terminal to move to the foreground in the state I last left it.

Comment: This just opens new windows for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1 - Remap gnome dock shortcut

1. Add gnome-terminal into dock (favortie), I move it to the third application, please change the number **3** in following article to the number you used.
2. Disable terminal shortcut in **Settings/Kebyaord/Keyboard Shortcuts**
3. Reset the shortcut to for start dock applications `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-3 "['<Ctrl><Alt>T']"`

## Method 2 (Xorg only) - Reset gnome default terminal

1. Create a script at `~/bin/single_gnome_terminal.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='gnome-terminal'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
  wmctrl -xa $SERVICE
else
  $SERVICE
fi
```

2. Enable execution permission

```bash
chmod +x ~/bin/single_gnome_terminal.sh`
```

3. Install `wmctrl`

```bash
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

4. Change default terminal

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec single_gnome_terminal.sh
```

References:

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/1194659
2. https://askubuntu.com/a/87109
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510376

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior if you use `Mod4+#` (`Mod4` = Super = "Windows" key, `#` is number in launcher) shortcut to open any application.

Comment: Yes I’m aware of that. Still, I have to have a terminal open to begin with. I meant when I press control + alt + t or open it up in Kupfer. I’m looking for the same behavior as – for example – Chrome: If an instance is open show me that instance, if there no instance open a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I generalized and simplfied @Mood 's script a bit.
Now it takes a command line parameter and use pgrep instead.

```
sudo apt-get install procps
```

The script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if pgrep $1
then
    wmctrl -xa $1
else
    $1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my own script, since I find it extremely useful:

1. If there is a gnome-terminal in the current workspace, then it brings
   it to the front and gives it focus
2. If there isn't any gnome-terminal in the current workspace, it switches the workspace and brings the first existing gnome-terminal it finds to front and gives it focus
3. If there are no gnome-terminal instances running, it opens a new
   instance, brings it to front and gives it focus

I configured Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut to run this script and I find it even more comfortable than Guake or Tilda.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# APP is the binary name you see when you do ps
APP="gnome-terminal"
# WIN_CLASS is the window class you see when you do wmctrl -lx
WIN_CLASS="gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal"

# Use the app from current workpace first, or any if not available
WORKSPACE=$(wmctrl -d | grep '\*' | cut -d ' ' -f1)
TPID=$(ps aux | pgrep $APP)
if [ "$TPID" ]
then
  QTERM_WIN=$(wmctrl -lx | grep $WIN_CLASS | grep $WORKSPACE  | awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}')
  if [ "$QTERM_WIN" ]
  then
    wmctrl -ia $QTERM_WIN
  else
    # No valid app found in the current workspace, switch to any
    QTERM_WIN=$(wmctrl -lx | grep $WIN_CLASS | awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}')
    wmctrl -ia $QTERM_WIN
  fi
else
  $APP &
fi
```

*I use it with QTerminal but I modified to fit your needs. Good luck*